# While loop does not get executed when method is called

Tags: c#, while-loop, return, boolean

The while loop

```
public static bool Authentication()
{
    bool isAuthenticated = false;
    int count = 4;
    while (isAuthenticated = false && count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please insert your 4 digit PIN");
        string pin = Console.ReadLine();
        if (pin == "1704")
        {
            isAuthenticated = true;
            return isAuthenticated;
        }
        else
        {
            count--;
            Console.WriteLine($"Wrong PIN: {count} Input remained ");
        }

    }

    return isAuthenticated;
}
```

I haven't been able to understand, when the debugger goes to the while loop, it does not execute it. It may be the condition of the while that does not fit the logic.

Comment: Have you considered using the Debugger on your code to find out the issue?

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator. `==` is the comparison operator.

Comment: As others have pointed out, the NOT operator (`!`) is better for checking the _false-ness_ of booleans. Another stylistic quibble: the variable name `count` usually counts up, not down. Consider naming it something like `triesLeft` to make its meaning clearer

Comment: You can just use while ( count > 0)  since  you return when isAuthenticated = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using the = as an assigning operator in the condition of the loop. You could try `!isAuthenticated` instead of `isAuthenticated == false` and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!isAuthenticate && count > 0)
```

I believe you were assigning false to isAuthenticate, so the condition could never be true.

Comment: Thank you! Yes Indeed I am. The assignment operator as @Geneku2 also have pointed out below is what is marking the issue.